# Use map() and map2() to run regressions and add fitted values to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, linear-regression, purrr

I want to regress each of a subset of columns of a data frame on another column of the same data frame (and on top on a subset of observations), and then append the fitted values as new and named columns to the original data frame. As an example, I'll use the EuStockMarkets data that comes with R, transformed into a data frame `df`.

```
df <- zoo::fortify.zoo(EuStockMarkets)
```

I would like to regress the columns `DAX`, `SMI`, `CAC`, and `FTSE` on `Index`

```
> colnames(df)
[1] "Index" "DAX"   "SMI"   "CAC"   "FTSE"
```

for values of `Index` up to `Index == 1996.877` using `{purrr}` functions to avoid a loop. Then, add the fitted values as new columns to `df` with names `DAX_fitted`, `SMI_fitted`, `CAC_fitted`, and `FTSE_fitted`.

I came up with two options until now:

```
fitted <- df %>% 
  select(-Index) %>% 
  names() %>% 
  paste(.,' ~ Index') %>%  
  map(as.formula) %>% 
  map2(., .y = rep(list(df %>% filter(Index < 1996.877)), length(.)), ~ predict(lm(.x, data = .y)))
```

which gives me a list of the fitted values or

```
lm <- df %>% 
    select(-Index) %>% 
    names() %>% 
    paste(.,' ~ Index') %>%  
    map(as.formula) %>% 
    map(lm, data = df %>% filter(Index < 1996.877))
```

which returns a list `lm` with regression results.

Ideas on how to complete these code lines to add the named fitted values to the original data frame? Thanks!

Comment: `fitted(lm(as.matrix(subset(df,,-Index)) ~ Index, df, Index < 1996.877))` should give you all the values you need. Change the colnames and `cbind` to your data. This method should be faster as it runs the linear model once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can use `mutate()` + `across()` to achieve that:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(Index < 1996.877) %>%
  mutate(across(-Index, ~ lm(.x ~ Index)$fitted.values,
                .names = "{.col}_fitted"))

# # A tibble: 1,400 × 9
#    Index   DAX   SMI   CAC  FTSE DAX_fitted SMI_fitted CAC_fitted FTSE_fitted
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#  1 1991. 1629. 1678. 1773. 2444.      1465.      1535.      1865.       2363.
#  2 1992. 1614. 1688. 1750. 2460.      1465.      1536.      1865.       2364.
#  3 1992. 1607. 1679. 1718  2448.      1466.      1538.      1865.       2365.
#  4 1992. 1621. 1684. 1708. 2470.      1467.      1539.      1865.       2366.
#  5 1992. 1618. 1687. 1723. 2485.      1468.      1541.      1865.       2367.
#  6 1992. 1611. 1672. 1714. 2467.      1468.      1542.      1865.       2368.
#  7 1992. 1631. 1683. 1734. 2488.      1469.      1544.      1865.       2369.
#  8 1992. 1640. 1704. 1757. 2508.      1470.      1545.      1866.       2370.
#  9 1992. 1635. 1698. 1754  2510.      1471.      1547.      1866.       2371.
# 10 1992. 1646. 1716. 1754. 2497.      1471.      1548.      1866.       2372.
# # ℹ 1,390 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

---

To minimally modify the code you have tried, you just need `set_names()` and `map_dfc()`:

```r
library(purrr)

df %>%
  select(-Index) %>% 
  names() %>%
  set_names(paste0, "_fitted") %>%
  map_dfc(~ lm(as.formula(paste(.x, "~ Index")), filter(df, Index < 1996.877))$fitted.values)

# # A tibble: 1,400 × 4
#    DAX_fitted SMI_fitted CAC_fitted FTSE_fitted
#         <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#  1      1465.      1535.      1865.       2363.
#  2      1465.      1536.      1865.       2364.
#  3      1466.      1538.      1865.       2365.
#  4      1467.      1539.      1865.       2366.
#  5      1468.      1541.      1865.       2367.
#  6      1468.      1542.      1865.       2368.
#  7      1469.      1544.      1865.       2369.
#  8      1470.      1545.      1866.       2370.
#  9      1471.      1547.      1866.       2371.
# 10      1471.      1548.      1866.       2372.
# # ℹ 1,390 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Answer (score 3):

As you are changing the y-values, you could run the regression only once, instead of running it multiple times. This is given in the code below:

```
values <- fitted(lm(as.matrix(subset(df,,-Index)) ~ Index, df, Index < 1996.877))
colnames(values) <- paste0(colnames(values), "_fitted")   
cbind(subset(df, Index < 1996.877), values)

       Index     DAX    SMI    CAC   FTSE DAX_fitted SMI_fitted CAC_fitted
1   1991.496 1628.75 1678.1 1772.8 2443.6   1464.602   1535.031   1864.686
2   1991.500 1613.63 1688.5 1750.5 2460.2   1465.356   1536.489   1864.810
3   1991.504 1606.51 1678.6 1718.0 2448.2   1466.110   1537.948   1864.934
4   1991.508 1621.04 1684.1 1708.1 2470.4   1466.864   1539.407   1865.059
5   1991.512 1618.16 1686.6 1723.1 2484.7   1467.618   1540.866   1865.183
6   1991.515 1610.61 1671.6 1714.3 2466.8   1468.373   1542.325   1865.307
7   1991.519 1630.75 1682.9 1734.5 2487.9   1469.127   1543.784   1865.431
```